# Calculate average in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made this console application and it works...but only when you enter small numbers in the input like 1 in 'ifrom', 2 in 'step', and 3 in 'to'...but when I enter bigger numbers in 'to' for example 100 it just do nothing!!! It even doesn't give me any error!
Thanks!

```
print("---Average2---"+"\n")

sum=0
average=0
counter=0

while True:
    ifrom=int(input("From: "))
    step=int(input("Step: "))
    to=int(input("To: "))
    while sum<=to:
        sum=ifrom+step
        counter+=1
        if sum==to:
            print("\n"+"The sum is: ",sum)
            average=sum/counter
            print("The average is: ",average,"\n")
            sum=0
            average=0
            counter=0
            break
```

Comment: Probably because `sum` never reaches `to`

Comment: `sum` is a function in Python, so avoid using it as a variable

Comment: @Arian Can you show us exact numbers that make the program "do nothing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons of this behavior

1. You're adding constantly `sum = ifrom + step` which is a constant value (in your example: `1 + 2 = 3`). So in every loop iteration your sum will be `3` and will never hit 100
2. Even if you fix the first problem, your example `sum` variable is going to be `1, 3, 5, ..., 99, 101, ...`. You're checking if the `sum` is 100 and the program is doing nothing, because it will never hit 100.

Possible solutions:

- use range syntax (recommended - you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72727217/16231079) solution )
- check if the variable reached 100 (instead of checking if it is equal 100) like below:

```py
print("---Average2---"+"\n")

average=0
counter=0
tmp=0

while True:
   ifrom=int(input("From: "))
   step=int(input("Step: "))
   to=int(input("To: "))
   tmp = ifrom
   sum = tmp
   while tmp<=to:
       tmp+=step
       sum+=tmp
       counter+=1
       if tmp>=to:
           if tmp>to:
             sum-=tmp
           print("\n"+"The sum is: ",sum)
           average=sum/counter
           print("The average is: ",average,"\n")
           sum=0
           average=0
           counter=0
           break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the nested while loop by using built-in Python functions like `range()`:

```
print("---Average2---"+"\n")

s=0
average=0
counter=0

while True:
    ifrom=int(input("From: "))
    step=int(input("Step: "))
    to=int(input("To: "))
    
    l = list(range(ifrom, to, step))
    s = sum(l)
    average = s/len(l)
    print("\n"+"The sum is: ",s)
    print("The average is: ",average,"\n")
    break
```

**Output:** *Note that the last number of the range `to` is not inclusive*

```
---Average2---

From: 0
Step: 1
To: 10

The sum is:  45
The average is:  4.5
```

Comment: Looking at OPs code - you and OP seem to be doing two different things..

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a value returned from *input()* to any function that might result in an exception without handling such a possibility. This answer includes a general-purpose function for handling input.

This code assumes that the specified range is inclusive.

```
def getInput(prompt, t=str):
    while True:
        v = input(f'{prompt}: ')
        try:
            return t(v)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input')

start = getInput('From', int)
step = getInput('Step', int)
to  = getInput('To', int)

total = list(range(start, to+1, step)) or [0]

sum_ = sum(total)

print(f'The sum is: {sum_}')
print(f'The average is: {sum_/len(total)}')
```

**Example:**

```
From: 1
Step: 5
To: 100
The sum is: 970
The average is: 48.5
```